# NServiceBus with Azure and XML serializer

Tags: azure, nservicebus

I am trying to switch a hosted worker process in Azure to use xml serializer instead of the default json serializer. I have done this by implementing IWantCustomInitialization like this:

```
public class BusInitialization : IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.Instance.XmlSerializer();
    }
}
```

However when I start the cloud solution, I get the following error:

> Exception when starting endpoint, error has been logged. Reason: Type NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.CompletionMessage was not registered in the serializer. Check that it appears in the list of configured assemblies/types to scan.

When I use no custom initialization and it goes to JsonSerializer, everything is fine. Does anyone have a suggestion where shall I look to? I use NSB 3.2.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thought this was fixed but I just checked, looks like in 3.2.8 the jsonserializer cannot yet be overriden easily. This has already been fixed on the dev branch but didn't get into release yet, it will be in the next one than.

If you can't wait for next release then you can work around this by replacing the AsA_Worker with your own role and role handler similar to this:

3.2.8 version https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/azure/Hosting/NServiceBus.Hosting.Azure/Roles/Handlers/WorkerRoleHandler.cs

develop version https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/develop/src/azure/Hosting/NServiceBus.Hosting.Azure/Roles/Handlers/WorkerRoleHandler.cs

Kind regards,
Yves

Comment: Thank you Yves. I got the dev branch too, will look at your code to understand how this works.